# Simple Group By In Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a table of expenses with the supplier and the amount like:

```
supplier  |  amount
=====================
Jon       |  13
Jon       |  12
Jane      |   3
Jack      |  15
Jon       |   2
Jack      |   8
```

Now I like to know how much I spent for each supplier. The result should be

```
supplier  |  total
=====================
Jon       |  27
Jane      |   3
Jack      |  23
```

The second table should get created dynamically so if I add "Jenny" to the first list it will show up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pivot table, reference your data table as the data source and place suppliers as row and amount as values. Make sure your settings for the value field is set to sum.

Then make sure your pivot setting is set to update whenever the datatable changes.

Comment: Can you link me to an (abstract) example. I'm not that familiar with pivot tables